# Build one to many relationship in PowerBI, when foreign keys are inside JSON array?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I am very new with Power BI, and my first task is to connect to a JSON datasource, I have an issue with arrays containing keys. Some context, let's say we have users and factories:

**users**

```js
[
    {
    "email": "user1@foo-bar.com",
    "user_id": "user1-id",
    "factory": ['factoryId1']
  },
  {
    "email": "user2@foo-bar.com",
    "user_id": "user2-id",
    "factory": ['factoryId2', 'factoryId1']
  }
]
```

**factories**

```
[
  {
    "factoryId": 'factoryId1',
    "factoryName": "London"
  },
  {
    "factoryId": 'factoryId2',
    "factoryName": "Moscow"
  }
]
```

Now the relationship I would like to build is:

```
+----------+------------+
| user_id  | factory_Id |
+----------+------------+
| user1-id | factoryId1 |
| user2-id | factoryId1 |
| user2-id | facotryId2 |
+----------+------------+
```

I have tried using the "Add as new Query" option:

[image]

After converting to a table and expanding the rows, I **almost** get the desired result:

```
+------------+
| factory_Id |
+------------+
| factoryId1 |
| factoryId1 |
| facotryId2 |
+------------+
```

The only thing missing here is the userIds. How do I add those Ids? (or maybe there is a simpler method of doing this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Expand to New Rows" (click on the double arrow icon)

[image]
[image]

The M query will look like this:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\gluisotto\Desktop\json.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"email", "user_id", "factory"}, {"Column1.email", "Column1.user_id", "Column1.factory"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.factory1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.factory")
in
    #"Expanded Column1.factory1"
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it generates duplicate records for the user.

Comment: It has to, you will need those rows if you want to create a relationship. (also this is exactly the result you are asking for).
If you have extra columns (like email) just delete it from this table

Comment: I have to disagree here; it certainly does not _have_ to. If the relationship should be build with only 2 tables, users and factories, then you are right. But the relationship can also be build with 3 tables, users, factories and a mapping table (like illustrated in my question). This will express the relationship, _and_ have the correct number of rows in the user table.

Comment: I took for granted to have 3 tables in the model. In the end, you should have "Users" (without factory column), "Factories" and the "Relationship table" which is obtained by using the data in the "user" table and expanding it (and keeping only the keys)

Comment: I get what you mean now, will try it out soon 

Comment: If you prefer I can edit the answer and add some more detail

Comment: This works, but seems like it is adding an "extra" request. I am trying to do some more research, as to how I can avoid this.